# Mod rewrite base URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes

I have several domains that I want to all rewrite to one domain. I don't want it to redirect because I want the URL to look like what the user has entered in. For example if they enter www.example.com I want it to load the page from www.sample.com/default.php?from=example

I have worked a little with rewriting if you have www.site.com/var1/var2 making it load www.site.com/index.php?one=var1&two=var2

Is it possible to do what I am looking for just through the .htaccess file? I tried looking around and couldn't exactly find what I was looking for

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sites are hosted on different servers or don't share a common document root, then you'll have to rely on mod_proxy and you can use the `P` rewrite rule flag. For example, these rules in an htaccess file in `www.example.com`'s document root:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.sample.com/default.php?from=%1 [L,P]
```

Will take the request `http://www.example.com/` and invisibly proxy it to `http://www.sample.com/default.php?from=example`. The browser's URL address bar will remain `http://www.example.com/`.

Note that the rule only matches against the request URI `/`. If you want to do more, you'd have to create the correct regular expression and grouping.

If you have redirects on the sample.com site, you'll need to employ [`ProxyPassReverse`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) to rewrite the redirects. Also see `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain` and `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath` if there are cookies involved.

If you can do this in vhost or server config instead, then consider simply using `ProxyPass` instead of mod_rewrite. The `ProxyPass` directive won't work inside htaccess files.

---

EDIT:

Seeing as how everything is in the same document root, you won't need to proxy anything. Simply:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.sample\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /default.php?from=%1 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified but I do have all of the domains hosted on the same server with the same root folder. I think a similar rule should work though. Thanks!

Comment: @TroyCosentino if they're all the same document root, then that changes everything. See the edit above.

Comment: Awesome, one last thing.. When I set up one of the "example" domains with my hosting, does it matter what folder I assign it to?

Comment: @TroyCosentino if there's not going to be any real content there, then it doesn't matter, as long as they're all the same server

Answer (score 0):

I use online generators.
Use this generator: [mod-rewrite](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/)